# recoger id de mysql y reenviarlos

Tags: php, mysql

necesito ayuda con esto para ver si alguien me ayuda...

desde la base de datos extraigo los usuarios(solo su id) y los paso a una tabla donde los trabajo como select(por ejemplo el user con id 1,2,3 lo relaciono con panes) y lugo los proceso en mi php.

mi problema es que necesito saber como identificar cuando seleccione el pan que id de usuario es que se relaciona con panes? espero haberme explicado bien!!

lo que necesito es que al seleccionar presente, ausente o excusa, puedas saber a qué fila y con qué id pertenece el registro?

Gracias, por la ayuda!!

ojo: no estoy buscando el id auto-generado, sino mas bien lograr identificar a cual estudiante pertenece el id?

```html
`    enviar.php

    $profesores= "SELECT * FROM t_persona";
$consulta_tabla_estudiante=mysqli_query($conexion,$profesores);


 while ($registroAsistencia = $consulta_tabla_estudiante->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))


  {


   $nombre=$registroAsistencia['id'];
   
  echo "<tr><div class='col-md-12 infocontec'  id='info'><form action='enviar_datosDos.php' name='asistencia' method='POST'>
     <td><fieldset>".$nombre."</fieldset></td>
     <td><fieldset>".$registroAsistencia['nombre']."</fieldset></td>
     <td><fieldset>".$registroAsistencia['apellido']."</fieldset></td>
     <td><fieldset><label><input type='radio' value='presente' id='presente' name='$nombre' id='presente' > Presente</label></fieldset></td>
     

     <td><fieldset><label><input type='radio'  value='ausente' id='ausente' name='$nombre' id='ausente'> Ausente</label></fieldset></td>


     <td><fieldset><label><input type='radio'  value='excusa' id='excusa' name='$nombre' id='excusa'> Excusa</label></fieldset></td>
     </div></tr>";
  
  }echo "<td><button type='submit' id='bEnviar' name='bEnviar'>GUARDAR</button></form></td>";
`
       
enviarDos.php

    $result = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT id FROM t_persona"); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
//var_dump($row);

$id=$row['id'];
if (isset($_POST['bEnviar'])) {


if (isset($_POST)) {

 $presente=$_POST['presente']='presente';

$sql="INSERT into asistencia (presente,id_persona)
        values ('$presente','".$id."')";
 echo $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);



 $ausente=$_POST['ausente']='ausente';

$sqlUno="INSERT into asistencia (ausente)
        values ('$ausente')";

  echo $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sqlUno);


 $excusa=$_POST['excusa']='excusa'; 


$sqlDos="INSERT into asistencia (excusa)
        values ('$excusa')";
 echo $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sqlDos);

 
}else {
 echo "error en la conexion<br>";


}
```

Comment: Se entiende más fácil si incluyes la estructura de las tablas *como texto* y datos de prueba *como texto*, así sabremos qué es lo que esperas obtener

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que pones en la pregunto, supongo que los usuarios deben registrarse o iniciar sesión antes de hacer eso. Bien, en php existen las **variables de sesión**.

Estas variables permiten guardar información importante sobre la sesión del usuario, como el nombre de usuario, y otros datos.

Estas variables van a existir siempre que el usuario permanezca con la sesión iniciada (a no ser que las elimines tú antes).

Por lo tanto, lo que tienes que hacer, en el momento en el que el usuario inicia sesión, es registrar una variable con el id del usuario:

```html
<?php 
session_start();

/* $_SESSION["nombreVariable"] = $valor; */
$_SESSION["userId"] = $id;
?>
```

Donde **$id** es el id del usuario.

**Nota:** No olvides, siempre que quieras acceder a las variables de sesión, poner `$session_start()`, si no ejecutas esta función, no podrás acceder a dichas variables.

Por último, cuando el usuario cierre sesión, ya no quieres que esas variables exitan, por lo que puedes cerrar la sesión usando la función:
`$session_destroy()`

Para saber más entra en la documentación de las [variables de sesión](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.session.php).

Comment: los usuarios no estan registrados(osea, solo estan inscritos, pero no tienen cuenta de login). estos datos ya estan almacenados en la bd.

Comment: Ah vale, entonces que es lo que muestras en el formulario?, es decir, las opciones de 'presente', 'ausente' y 'excusa' a que afecta, a los usuarios?

Comment: son varios usuarios, cada usuario tiene 'presente', 'ausente' y 'excusa, desde la base de datos traigo los nombre y su respectivo id; como tengo varios estudiantes registrado, necesito saber cuando uno de ellos este presente o ausente/